# Power BI including data both sides of a one to many relationship

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a table in Power BI which lists the:

- Container Image Details
- Container Details
- Virtual Machine details (in the entity table)
- plus the vulnerability data

Power BI happily accepts me placing data from wiz_entities, wiz_containers and wiz_container_images in the same able, however if I drop in data from the wiz_findings or wiz_vulnerabilities tables it complains about relationships.

I've even tried added two further tables mapping the containers & entities to findings, Power BI will allow the entities connection but not containers because it creates ambiguity.

Can anyone give me any tips on how to get the layout I want?  (I realise some of the fields will be in duplicate)

[image: Model Relationships]

To simplify it doesn't like me adding fields from wiz_containers & wiz_findings, even if I enable bi-directional filtering

[image]